# All users being logged in as System Account

Tags: sharepoint-2010, administration, foundation

So I have my little Sharepoint single server farm all setup and everything was running pretty smoothly until I noticed this happening last week:

Every time someone logs in, they get logged in as "System Account" instead of "Domain\User"

I've done some extensive searching on here and Google, but the only solution that I came up with was that it was an App Pool Identity problem

Any suggestions?

**

### EDIT:

**

**I just wanted to say for the sake of anyone Googling this that here is how I fixed it:
In the Administration Page, navigate your way to Farm Credentials.
From there look at your Farm Account in the drop down menu, and make sure that user is set to a profile with enough privileges. Mine was set to NT\AUTHORITY or SYSTEM\NETWORK (I can't remember which; I've since stopped working with Sharepoint) and I changed it to DOMAIN\USER. 
After restarting Sharepoint and IIS everything worked and all the users were logging it with DOMAIN\USER instead of "System Account"**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are on the right track. I would first check application pool security account. Is it possible that you selected a domain group that contains all of your users?

Comment: Thanks for your input Rich and you were right about the domain group. However when I switched back and tried some other identities I'm still stuck with the same problem. 

I am working on it though and as soon as I find something I will be sure to post it back here.

Answer (score 0):

Also, after actions that Rich Bennema provide, maybe need to perform issreset to applay changes.